# decrypting salesforce custom field in php

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, salesforce

I am creating a signin page in php using heroku, I have created a  custom text(encryption) field in Salesforce which i want to decrypt in php in order to compare the user entered data with the decrypted data. How can i achieve this? Kindly help if anyone has solution for the same.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    if (base64_decode($row[1]) == $_POST['password']) {
        echo "You are a validated user/n";
        echo "HELLO" . $_POST['email'];
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT Email , Password__c FROM salesforce.contact ;"; 
$result= pg_query($query); 
$row = pg_fetch_row($result);
echo "Row password " .$row[1]; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Post password " .$_POST['password']; 
echo "<br>";
```

Output: 
($row[2]==>)Row password *********** 
Post password 123456789
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoAQq.png)

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal: while($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
{
 if(base64_decode($row[1]) ==  $_POST['password'])
 {
  echo "You are a validated user/n";
  echo "HELLO" .$_POST['email'];
  exit;
 }
}

Comment: What's the problem you have with this code?

Comment: The data is not getting compared with the post data

Comment: Can you post data returned from your postgres database? Are you sure about the encryption method and that its definitely base64? Please add the print_r($row); inside the while loop and print the result, like: `while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { 
    print_r($row);
} }`. Add that to your question.

Comment: yes the data is getting printed by $row.. i am not sure if it is base 64..  the encryption method used by salesforce is classic encryption

Comment: Please add that output here, so we can see what's it. Also add the value of particular `$_POST['password']` variable for that row you copy.

Comment: Code:
$query = "SELECT Email , Password__c FROM salesforce.contact ;";
$result= pg_query($query);
$row = pg_fetch_row($result);
$arr = pg_fetch_all_columns($query);
echo "Row email " .$row[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "Post email " .$_POST['email'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Row password " .$row[1];
echo "<br>";
echo "Post password " .$_POST['password'];
echo "<br>";

Output:
Row email sheela@gmail.com
Post email gk@gmail.com
Row password ***********
Post password 123456789

Comment: Please post your code in your question and not in the comments.  In order for us to help you we need to see the value for `$row[1]`

Comment: You need to post the actual value instead of `Row password *********** `.

Comment: The data being encrypted, it is not getting compared with the user $_POST data

Comment: The *********** does not help us.  We need to see the actual or encrypted value for the password!

Comment: @Joseph_J That data i am calling it from salesforce.. and it is comming in that format.. I want to convert that ******* into string so that i can compare the data

Comment: @Joseph_J i have selected text(encrypted) as datatype in salesforce

Comment: I am not familiar with salesforce.

Comment: Goto you database and copy the password directly from the database and paste it in your question.

Comment: What your doing is all wrong.  You are never going to be able to hash your $_POST['password'] to match the password you get back from your db.  Most passwords are hashes and the hashes are constantly different from each other and can not be directly compared.  Rethink what it is that you are trying to accomplish and try a different solution to your problem.

Comment: I want you to `print_r($row)` and post the result.

Comment: Also post the DDL of `salesforce.contact` table.

Comment: It is the custom field I have created .. There also the data will be shown in **** format.. i don't want to convert $_Post data to encryted format.. instead i want to decrypt the row[1] data which is comming from salesforce

Comment: @Aishwarya what you are asking is simply impossible to do in my opinion. You need to provide more information on how you imported your data from Salesforce to Postgres, how your data is stored in your db etc to give you a proper answer. Otherwise we are just assuming things and post which will not be accurate. However, I don't believe it's possible to decrypt the field. What you can do is find the proper encryption method used by SF, and then encrypt your `password` value using it and compare it against the hash. But if you only have asterisks (*) it will be impossible.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I am using heroku connect and Heroku Postgresql to link salesforce and my php page.. a copy of salesforce data is stored in that postgres..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't know how the data in Salesforce is encrypted. By default, the data returned from a query on those field is just `******`, and there's no way for an external application to decrypt this.

If you want to see the values in those fields, you need the querying user to have the `View Encrypted Data` permission, which can be given on the user profile or through a permission set.

[image]

Once your user has this permission, they will be able to see the plain-text values of the encrypted text field in:

- the ui
- the bulk api
- the rest api
- the soap api
- debug logs (although not when serializing the containing sObject)

Comment: even if i change the user permission.. would i be able to compare that data through query?

Comment: i changed the user permission but still the output is same

Comment: i want to access that decrypted text in php.. not in salesforce

Comment: @Aishwarya If you want the decrypted text in php, you will have to query it already decrypted. Salesforce doesn't give you a way to decrypt it yourself.

Comment: Do you mean that i cant use text(encrypted) in order to access that data in php?

Comment: @Aishwarya it sounds like now the data in your Heroku db needs to be refreshed so that it will have the plain text values since that is where your php application is querying from. If you look at Salesforce directly, you will see the real values instead of the `*****`. You just need to get those plain-text values over to Heroku.

Comment: i refreshed the data.. but in heroku connect it is showing Current Salesforce as 123456789 but current database as *********. That is, the data is been shown in salesforce but not in heroku connect

Comment: @Aishwarya Who's user credentials are being used to authorize heroku connect? It sounds like they might still be missing the view encrypted data permission.

Comment: those are my credentials..i can view that encrypted data in salesforce but not in heroku